# SQL command to write and read all values from a table with 4 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with 4 fields,

```
id - INT Primary
description - TEXT
postdate - DATE
username - TEXT
```

I was able to connect to database

I am trying to use the following command to write to database

```
INSERT INTO userdata(description, postdate, username) VALUES(@description, @postdate, @username)
```

But when I try to run a SELECT query nothing shows up

```
SELECT `id`, `description`, `postdate`, `username` FROM `userdata` WHERE 1
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE 1
```

Why does this happen?

I need to save the entries into the database 1 row at a time (description, postdate, username)

And then I need to retrieve all of the data from the table one row at a time ignoring entries that are more than 30 days old

Can someone please help me construct the correct queries for each one?

Comment: You may need to commit the `insert`.

Comment: Save yourself some hurt later on, and don't use `TEXT` for a column named `postdate`.

Comment: As Joel said, remember that SQL has both DATE and DATETIME value types.
Also, where are you writing this query? In a program in another language? Or is this just a command you're trying to execute from your MySql DBMS?

Comment: This is from Xamarin.Forms but I assume the query would work in any language

Comment: I modified question to use DATE instead of TEXT

Comment: Your SQL query would indeed run from any language provided you have the proper connection to the instance, but it's important to always include that language/framework because the issue may actually be coming from somewhere else. For example, I see that you're inserting values by using parameters, it could be that your code for getting the value of those parameters is not correct so you're not actually passing data to it.

Not saying this is your case, because it doesn't seem to be, but just showing why it's important to indicate the language and all the related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` statement needs to indicate what's the field you expect to be 1.

I assume you meant the ID.
So it would be

```
SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, POSTDATE, USERNAME
FROM Userdata
WHERE ID = 1
```

You do not need to wrap your column/table names in backticks if they're just 1 word.

I'd also like to point out some basic good practices in SQL: Naming conventions state columns should be All caps. Tables should be Pascal case.

Comment: I tried this  `"SELECT id, description, postdate, username FROM userdata WHERE id = 1 " ` it still returned empty set. `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)`  Is my insert command incorrect? What command would I use to write all 4 of these into 1 row to make sure it works?

Comment: Try running `SELECT * FROM Username`, just that, no `WHERE` statement.

If it returns empty, your database is not saving the values.

Whenever you're programming SQL queries for a program in another language, I'd recommend you to open your DBMS and try the individual queries to make sure the SQL is correct. SQL will also be better at telling you what went wrong with the query if there's errors in it. Also I don't know if you've noticed, but your INSERT operation has no closing parentheses for the VALUES statement. If that's actually on your query, that's a problem. Close that parentheses.